# Access Generic API endpoints with Terraform

Tags: api, terraform, terraform0.12+

I have an endpoint security provider (FortiEDR/enSilo) that has a RESTful API interface, and I want to put code in my Terraform script that creates/destroys users on the system.

Since there is no provider in Terraform for this security endpoint solution, is there a way that one can simply reference generic APIs?

(I looked online and didn't see any examples that I could use as a starting point).

Comment: Mastercard has made a generic REST API provider.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just found it - https://github.com/Mastercard/terraform-provider-restapi